# Facebook UI dialog, image from amazon server

Tags: php, facebook, api, amazon-web-services, get

I am using a FB.UI dialog with method "feed" to share a link on facebook because I need to dynamically set an image at the moment of the post. 
My image comes from an AWS cloud-generated image on elasticbeanstalk. 
I can access the [image](http://tranceprocessor-staging.elasticbeanstalk.com/thumbnail/http://files.parse.com/3c2b4464-fa36-4094-b1b7-1fca1675f1ba/4d2c1367-c23c-4be5-ba74-cb188bf6a117-image.jpg?q=70&o=play) from any browser.

but the I get the following error:

https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/app_full_proxy.php?app=1435541680000634&v…5f1ba%2F4d2c1367-c23c-4be5-ba74-cb188bf6a117-image.jpg%3Fq%3D70%26o%3Dplay 404 (Not Found)

and the dialog shows no image.

Any idea of where the issue could come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting what solved it:

Facebook dialog would encode it and remove a `/` in `http://`

I removed all the `http://` and let FB assume them and it's working now!